# QPlainTextEdit 5.3 - Select and Move Text Programmatically (C++)

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to select some text programmatically and move it upwards (or downwards) replacing the text above it on a QPlainTextEdit and keeping the TextFormat.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked what QtCreator does? I am sure that you could take their code as a reference.

Comment: The link is broken for that example.

Comment: I have not sent any links. :)

Comment: I know. But there is one in another StackOverflow thread. Thought that what you were mentioning.

Comment: Hmm? I merely referred to the QtCreator codebase which does exactly this functionality in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
int count = 5;
int startPos= 5;
int endPos = startPos+count;
QTextCursor c = ui->plainTextEdit->textCursor();
c.setPosition(startPos);
c.setPosition(endPos, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
ui->plainTextEdit->setTextCursor(c);
QString txt = ui->plainTextEdit->textCursor().selectedText();
qDebug() << txt;
ui->plainTextEdit->textCursor().deleteChar();
c.setPosition(startPos);
c.setPosition(startPos - count, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
ui->plainTextEdit->setTextCursor(c);
ui->plainTextEdit->textCursor().deleteChar();
ui->plainTextEdit->textCursor().insertText(txt);
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

It was replaced, my example shows all needed methods and manipulations such as selection, text getting, removing etc)

Comment: Thanks for your code. Thats what I needed. I just had to change a little bit to shift up/down instead of left. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to copy and maintain the text format ?

Comment: @Yore selectedText should save format too, also you can copy in my example there is txt variable it is a selected text, so you can paste it where you want without using `deleteChar`

Comment: Actually, we need to use this: textCursor.selection().toHtml(); Otherwise it does not copy the format.